# Call insecure GRPC Service running in docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'am trying to call an insecure (http) GRPC Service from a Console App (both the GRPC Service and the Console Client are running in docker) and I'am getting the following exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|281_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.SocketConnectivitySubchannelTransport.TryConnectAsync(ConnectContext context)")'
```

Althougth the `StatusCode="Unavailable"` I can confirm that the service is responding request because I can call the Service from Postman without problems.

My `docker-compose.override.yml` file is the follow:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  grpcservice:
    container_name: grpcservice
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8000:80" 
      #- "8001:443"
    networks:
      - grpc-network
  
  grpcclient:
    container_name: grpcclient
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "GrpcServiceUrl=http://grpcservice:8000"
    networks:
      - grpc-network
    depends_on:
      - grpcservice

networks:
  grpc-network:
    external: false
```

And the code of my GRPC client (`Program.cs` in the console App) is the following:

```
public static void CallGrpcService()
{
    string serviceUrl = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GrpcServiceUrl");
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(serviceUrl);
    var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
    var reply = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
    Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The complete solution along with the docker and compose files [are in this repo in my github](https://github.com/Ewerton/GrpcTest)

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve successfully executed the code supplied in the git repo of the question, but only after applying the following modifications:

- Configured Kestrel to listen on any ip, and on port other than `80`:

  ```
   builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
   {
       // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
       options.ListenAnyIP(8000, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
   });
  ```
- In `docker-compose.override.yml`, `grpcservice` then should have ports mapping:

  ```
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
  ```
- For easier setup I removed volumes definitions as secure transport is not subject of the discussion.
- Removed `Http2UnencryptedSupport` switch from client, as it is no longer needed in .net 5 or later. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client).

Here is the output of the docker compose:

```
Creating grpcservice ... done
Creating grpcclient  ... done
Attaching to grpcservice, grpcclient
grpcservice    | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
grpcservice    |       Overriding address(es) 'https://+:443, http://+:80'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
grpcservice    | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
grpcservice    |       Now listening on: http://[::]:8000
grpcservice    | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
grpcservice    |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
grpcservice    | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
grpcservice    |       Hosting environment: Development
grpcservice    | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
grpcservice    |       Content root path: /app
grpcclient     | Greeting: Hello GreeterClient
grpcclient exited with code 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Now, I'm wondering how you find this solution because the official docs just mention the [context switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client) and nothing about kestrel configuration

Comment: You're welcome. Since I'm using MacOS I followed the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#unable-to-start-aspnet-core-grpc-app-on-macos), except I used ListenAnyIP call because of the docker.